# How to remove white line in ion refresher ionic 2

Tags: html, ionic2

[image]

This is my code to make an ion refresher, with the background color red, but when I added ion refresher code, there is a white line. How to remove it?

```
 <ion-refresher (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)" style="background-image: url(assets/imgs/backgrounds.png)">
  <ion-refresher-content
    pullingIcon="arrow-dropdown"
    pullingText="Pull to Refresh"
    refreshingText="Refreshing...">
  </ion-refresher-content> 
</ion-refresher>
```

Comment: can you add a screenshot of what you mean?

Comment: @SurajRao I have edited my question, please look at the link Url to see the ss pict

Comment: sry.. I am not able to understand from the image.. is the barcode part of the pull to refresh?

Comment: yes,, barcode is part of pull refresh content,  but not part of refresher code, i dnt know where is the white comes from, but when I remove the ion refresh code, big white line is dissapear.